# What is the formular to find the total number of ways to build a ring out of square tiles with a hole in the middle?

Tags: geometry

Given a total number of square tiles, is there a formula to calculate the number of possible ways to build a ring with a hole using all of the tiles?

Rules:
The wall can only be $1$ tile wide.
the hole must be at least one tile wide.
Rotating the Edges does not add to the number on combinations. i.e $5 \times 3 = 3 \times 5$ etc.

ie: given $12$ Tiles:

$3$ Tiles = height / $5$ Tiles wide
$4$ Tiles = height / $4$ Tiles wide

= $2$ possible combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $T$ tiles, we will need to put $4$ in the corners and (hopfully) there will be an even number of tiles to build the walls. So let $t=\frac{T-4}{2}$. Now it is easier to think about the internal rectangle that they encircle; In your example $t=4$ and this could give rise to rectangles $1 \times 3$,$2 \times 2$ or $3 \times 1$ and with this double counting the sequence would be $t-1$
\begin{eqnarray*}
1,2,3,4,\cdots
\end{eqnarray*}
Removing the double counting gives the sequence
\begin{eqnarray*}
1,1,2,2,3,3,4,\cdots
\end{eqnarray*}
or $ \lceil \frac{t}{2} \rceil $.

Comment: For $T=36$, we have $t=16$ and $ \lceil \frac{16}{2} \rceil =8 $ ways ... $1 \times 15, 2 \times 14, \cdots, 8 \times 8 $ ... $8$ ways.